# Ganache GUI installation error

Tags: truffle, nodejs, ganache, npm

node version v12.8.0,npm version 6.10.2

I followed the below steps to install the ganache GUI but I got the error

```
$mkdir ~/ganache
$git clone https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache.git
$npm install
$npm start
```

error:

> ganache@2.1.1-beta.0 start /home/nithin/ganache
>   electron-forge start

```
✔ Checking your system
✔ Locating Application

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Could not determine Electron version. Make sure that 'npm install' (or 'yarn') has been run before invoking electron-forge.
Error: Could not determine Electron version. Make sure that 'npm install' (or 'yarn') has been run before invoking electron-forge.
at /usr/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/dist/util/rebuild.js:26:13
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at Generator.tryCatcher (/usr/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at PromiseSpawn._promiseFulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/generators.js:97:49)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/generators.js:201:15
at /usr/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/dist/util/rebuild.js:63:17
at /usr/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/dist/api/start.js:105:33
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at Generator.tryCatcher (/usr/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at PromiseSpawn._promiseFulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/generators.js:97:49)
at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:579:26)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:619:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:699:18)
at _drainQueueStep (/usr/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
at _drainQueue (/usr/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
at Async._drainQueues (/usr/lib/node_modules/electron-forge/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ganache@2.1.1-beta.0 start: `electron-forge start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ganache@2.1.1-beta.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nithin/.npm/_logs/2019-08-14T11_24_08_546
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an alternative method. You can download ganache from the below link

```
$https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/releases/download/v1.2.2/ganache-1.2.2-x86_64.AppImage
```

After it has downloaded execute the below command in terminal

```
 $cd Downloads
 $sudo chmod a+x ganache-1.2.2-x86_64.AppImage
```

Now search for ganache and double click on it and press yes on the pop-up box. Ganache GUI will be started

Comment: thanks, Nithin it's worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is not compatible with node 12.x
I managed to install it with node 10.16.0

I also had to install the following to solve some error messages:

```xml
sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
```

Comment: after which command I have to run those command.

Comment: I downgraded node to 10.16.0 and run those commands then also I got the same error

Comment: I had slightly different error message than you had. Perhaps deleting the node_modules directory and do npm install again helps. Especially check the "npm install" errrors and try to fix them. I did the extra apt install' after error messages showed up at npm start.